# How to speed up consecutive program startup under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, startup

I've written two relatively small programs using C. Both of them comunnicate with each other using textual data. Program A generates some problems from given input, B evaluates them and creates input for another iteration of A.

Here's a bash script that I currently use:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do 
  ./A data > data2;
  ./B data2 > data;
done
```

The problem is that since what A and B do is not very time consuming, most of the time is spent (as I suppose) in starting apps up. When I measure time the script runs I get:

```
$ time ./bash.sh
real    0m10.304s
user    0m4.010s
sys     0m0.113s
```

So my main question is: is there any way to communicate data beetwen those two apps faster? I don't want to integrate them into one application, because I'm trying to build a toolset with independent, easly communicating tools (as was suggested in "The Art of Unix Programming" from which I'm learning the way to write reusable software).

PS. The data and data2 files contain sets of data needed in whole at once by those applications (so communicating by for e.g. one line of data at time is impossible).

Thanks for any suggestions.

cheers,

kajman

Comment: Based on information you provided, there is no way to logically conclude that startup is the bottleneck. You need to investigate more.

Comment: are you thinking of `pipe`s? In a shell script, you would do `./A | ./B > outData.txt` This assumes that your `./A` writes to stdout AND that `./B` can read from stdin (or a file). Good luck.

Comment: Why do you think most of the time is spent at startup? Have you profiled the app? Is the timing mentioned for a couple of startups of the applications, or just one?

Comment: @buddhabrot I haven't profiled it. I've assumed it by the output of time function, because I thouth that if it spends 10s in total, and only 4s in user time it means something like 40% of time is spend in calulations, and rest in switching beetwen apps. Apparently, by your answers, I made a wrong assumption. The time output is for the script given (1000 runs).

Comment: The system time could also be I/O related, allocating memory, etc..

Comment: @buddhabrot I've tried putting data and data2 files in /dev/shm and it didn't make any differance, so I think disk I/O is not the problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Can you create [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) ?

```
mkfifo data1
mkfifo data2
./A data1 > data2 &
./B data2 > data1
```

If your application is reading and writing in a loop, this could work :)

Comment: But how can I get the startup data (the file data1 must contain valid data generated by B in order to start running) in the picture? I've ommited it in the original question, but I always 'init' the whole thing by generating startup data by B.

Comment: Well, if B is prior to A, invert both line :)

Answer (score 1):

If you used pipes to transfer the stdout of program A to the stdin of program B you would remove the need to write the file "data2" each loop.

```
./A data1 | ./B > data1
```

Program B would need to have the capability of using input from stdin rather than a specified file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a program run faster, you need to understand what is making the program run slowly.  The field of computer science dedicated to measuring the performance of a running program is called [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Once you discover which internal portion of your program is running slow, you can generally speed it up.  How you go about speeding up that item depends heavily on what "the slow part" is doing and how it is "being done".

Several people have recommended pipes for moving the data directly from the output of one program into the input of another program.  Assuming you rewrite your tools to handle input and output in a piped manner, this *might* improve performance.  Again, it depends on *what* you are doing and *how* you are doing it.

For example, if your tool just fixes windows style end-of-lines into unix style end-of-lines, the program might read in one line, waiting for it to be available, check the end-of-line and write out the line with the desired end-of-line.  Or the tool might read in all of the data, do a replacement call on each "wrong" end-of-line in memory, and then write out all of the data.  With the first solution, piping speeds things up.  With the second solution piping doesn't speed up anything.

The reason is is truly so hard to answer such a question is because the fix you need *really* depends on the code you have, the problem you are trying to solve, and the means by which you are solving it now.  In the end, there isn't always a 100% guarantee that the code can be sped up; however, virtually every piece of code has opportunities to be sped up.  Use profiling to speed up the parts that are slow, instead of wasting your time working on a part of your program that is only called once, and represents 0.001% of the program's runtime.

Remember if you speed up something that is 0.001% of your program's runtime by 50%, you actually only sped up your entire program by 0.0005%.  Use profiling to determine the block of code that's taking up 90% of your runtime and concentrate on it.

Comment: I've profiled some programs before using gprof. But I don't know how to profile a 'complex' program like this script. By complex I mean that it is made of two or more independent programs. Any suggestions about that? Also, as I mentioned in my original post, I cannot use the data line-by-line because of the underlying problem.

Comment: @kajman, time each program independently, using known data sets and profile them in combination.  Decide which step is slow, App "A" runtime, App "B" runtime, or the time between the two (total time - app A time - app B time).  If the time between the two is slow then look to faster ways to implement the combination in the scripting language; however, odds are good that either A is putting out output faster than B can accept it, or that B is waiting for A to finish.  It is somewhat rare that the shell is the "slow" step.

Answer (score 0):

I do have to wonder why, if A and B depend on each other to run, do you want them to be part of an independent toolset.

One solution is a compromise between the two:

1. Create a library that contains A.
2. Create a library that contains B.
3. Create a program that spawns two threads, 1 containing A and 2 containing B.
4. Create a semaphore that tells A to run and another that tells B to run.
5. After the function that calls A in 1, increment B's semaphore.
6. After the function that calls B in 2, increment A's semaphore.

Another possibility is to use file locking in your programs:

1. Make both A and B execute in infinite loops (or however many times you're processing data)
2. Add code to attempt to lock both files at the beginning of the infinite loop in A and B (if not, sleep and try again so that you don't do anything until you have the lock).
3. Add code to unlock and sleep for longer than the sleep in step 2 at the end of each loop.

Either of these solve the problem of having the overhead of launching the program between runs.

Comment: To answer your first concern: I'm trying to make some tools to use artificial evolution, neural networks and so to optimize some problems. Here program A is evolving output form program B which is generating and evaluating fittness of the given problems. I'd like to have A totally independent of B,C,D and other problem-generating programs (so for e.g. I can optimize neural networks using A to, which in turn can operate on data from other programs in toolset)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Is the answer helpful?

Comment: @kajman, you should update the question with the description you just gave here.  The additional context will help people give better answers than solve your actual problem, rather than your distillation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly not application startup which is the bottleneck. Linux will end up caching large portions of your programs, which means that launching will progressively get *faster* (to a point) the more times you start your program.

You need to look elsewhere for your bottleneck.